# MYSQL trigger giving errors

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

Accounts table: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqL1E.png)

MYSQL terminal: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dgF7k.png)

I'm making a trigger to the Accounts table that will respond to any update or insertion into the database that would give an account type any value other than credit, checking, or cash the value cash.

I tried implementing the trigger (it compiled) but it's giving me an error whenever I try to add something that's not cash, credit, and checking. What could cause/fix this error?

Comment: Please post your code directly into the question.
Links can die/be unreliable

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

Rather than executing `insert`, replace the `OLD` value of the column with the new value you want by setting a property of `NEW`:

```
IF OLD.type <> 'cash' and OLD.type <> 'credit' and OLD.type <> 'checking' THEN
    SET NEW.type = 'cash'
END IF;
```

The overriden value stored in `NEW.type` will be inserted into the table when your trigger finishes.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is fairly self explanatory. A `TRIGGER` is prohibited from modifying the table that fired the trigger.

The restriction is documented in the MySQL Reference Manual

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html

> A stored function or trigger cannot modify a table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the statement that invoked the function or trigger.

---

In a `BEFORE INSERT` and `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger, we can assign values to columns of the row that is being inserted or updated, by referencing   `NEW.column_name`

For example

```
 -- check if value assigned to `col` is valid
 IF NEW.col IN ('cash','checking','credit') THEN
    -- it is valid, so do nothing 
    DO 0;
 ELSE
   -- value isn't valid, so override the provided value
   SET NEW.col = 'cash';
 END IF;
```

---

An empty `BEGIN END` block would be preferred to the `DO 0;` statement. Also, be sure to anticipate `NULL` values and ensure those are handled appropriately. (Note that a "not equals" comparison to `NULL` will return `NULL`, not true or false.)

```
 -- check if value assigned to `col` is valid
 IF NEW.col IN ('cash','checking','credit') THEN
    -- it is valid, so do nothing 
    BEGIN END;
 ELSE
   -- value isn't valid, so override the provided value
   SET NEW.col = 'cash';
 END IF;
```